# Daemon using MSAL to MSGraph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm getting the error *AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion audience claim does not match Realm issuer*

when running this code.

```
    string[] scopes = new string[]{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};
var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var cert = certStore.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().First(c => c.Thumbprint == "XXX-XXX etc");
var cas = new ClientAssertionCertificate(cert);
var cc = new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(cas);
var client = new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication("XX-XXX etc", "http://localhost", cc, new TokenCache(), new TokenCache() );
var authResult = await client.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);
var dap = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(rm => 
{
    rm.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
});
var gClient = new GraphServiceClient(dap);
gClient.Me.Dump();
```

Error occurrs on the call to `AcquireTokenForClientAsync()` method.

I can not find any online documentation for MSAL and Daemon clients where no user authentication is possible.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I needed to use the second overload of the `ConfidentialClientApplication` constructor, and supply the authorisation like this.

```
string authorityFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
string tennantId = "xxx-xx-xx";
```

then

`var client = new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication("xxx-x-xx etc", string.Format(authorityFormat, tennantId), "http://localhost", cc, new TokenCache(), new TokenCache() );`

The code [Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2/blob/master/UserSync/Controllers/SyncController.cs) pointed me in the right direction.